# Unresolved Inclusion: <thread>

Tags: c++, eclipse, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, include

I presume this is not a code problem, but a resource problem.

My IDE is C++ Eclipse. I referenced Kernel32.lib and I can include libraries like iostream, string and time.h. However, I can't include thread.

Can anybody please name the .lib that contains thread?

@edit

I am using Microsoft Visual C++ Toolchain, 2010v

Comment: The [`<thread>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread) support library is C++11 or later. Include your toolchain and version info in your question. And the error you're reporting appears to be compile-time; not link-time. A lib has nothing to do with it if that is the case. Regardless, including the *exact* error message **verbatim** in your question is highly advised.

Comment: That is literally the exact error message:

Unresolved Inclusion: <thread>

I remember I had a similar error with other headers before I linked Kernel32.lib

Comment: VS did not add `<thread>` support until VS2012 (and it was sketchy then, VS2013 is better). Do some hunting in your tools, but I'm betting you're running VS2010 (which had decent C++03x support, but no standard threading) or prior .

Comment: Yes you are right, I found it now. It is VS2010. So your advice would be getting newer VS? Post that as answer so I can select it and upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS did not add `<thread>` support until VS2012 (and it was sketchy then, VS2013 is better).

I'm betting you're running VS2010 (which had decent C++03x support, but no standard threading) or prior. You can download VS2013 Express for free from MS (doesn't have all of the whiz bang tools that pro and ultimate editions do, but it has a compiler and a great debugger for windows). I suggest you update your toolset to a later VS.

Best of luck.